# Dimension Problem when Training with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wish to build a model that with an input of `(1, 495, 383, 1)` dimension. Therefore, I set a tensor with the shape of `(1, 512, 512, 1)` and then change it to `(1, 495, 383, 1)` by defining a `slice()` function as follows:

```py
def slice(x, n, h1, h2, w1, w2, d):
    return tf.reshape(x[n, h1:h2, w1:w2, d], shape=(1, h2-h1, w2-w1, 1))
```

Then, I apply this function with the following argument:

```py
x = Lambda(slice, arguments={'n':x.shape[0], 'h1': 0, 'h2': rna, 'w1': 0, 'w2': diseas, 'd':1})(x)
```

However, when I train this model, an error happened. The error sentences are as follows:

```
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 12256 elements to shape [1,495,383,1] (189585 elements) for '{{node model_6/model_4/lambda_1/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](model_6/model_4/lambda_1/strided_slice, model_6/model_4/lambda_1/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [1,32,383,1], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,495,383,1].
```

Could you please provide me with some solutions to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What are `rna` and `diseas`? Also why do this instead of `tf.reshape(x, [1, 495, 383, 1])`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure value of n and d are appropriate. You will find the solution by following the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda

import numpy as np

#The input...
x=np.random.rand(1,512,512,1)

def slice(x, n, h1, h2, w1, w2, d):
    return tf.reshape(x[n, h1:h2, w1:w2, d], shape=(1, h2-h1, w2-w1, 1))

#Let's just demonstrate is the reshaping possible...take care of parameters n and d carefully
for i in range(5):
    n=0
    h1=np.random.randint(0,256)
    h2=np.random.randint(257,511)
    w1=np.random.randint(0,256)
    w2=np.random.randint(257,511)
    d=0
    try:
        print("From input shape: ",x.shape," ...the...")
        uus=slice(x,n,h1,h2,w1,w2,d)
        print("...reshaping is done succesfully, resulting in a shape: ",uus.shape)
    except:
        print("...reshaping is not possible!")

#And then let's input the data...for testing...
rna=1
diseas=1

#Make sure the value of n and value of d is appropriate...as demonstrated above...
x_after = Lambda(slice, arguments={'n':x.shape[0]-1, 'h1': 0, 'h2': rna, 'w1': 0, 'w2': diseas, 'd':0})(x)

print(x_after)
```

...which should result somehow like:

[image]

...for the value of last line when everything works well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I met some problems when applying your code. When I apply `x = Lambda(slice, arguments={'n':x.shape[0]-1, 'h1': 0, 'h2': rna, 'w1': 0, 'w2': diseas, 'd':0})(x)`, it happened `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'` in the TypeError. Could you please give me an explanation about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZimuWang ....hmmm...do you succesfully get the same result like me when running the code in the answer? But, after you itself try to apply the code mentionded below with other data, you get this error?

Comment: I successfully get the same result when running your code. However, when I changed the dimension in my project as the code you provided me, it went wrong as the error statements.